# How do you execute a command inside a process in Docker?

Tags: docker

How can/could I run a command inside a process in docker. So for instance if I was running `apt-get curl` in a container it would want a input of `Y/n`. How could I accept that? **(yes i know about the `--assume-yes` argument)**

Comment: If you know about `-y` flag, then what is your question?

Comment: @aerokite That this was a question, I just want to be able to run commands inside of a interactive terminal running in a docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your terminal, execute the following command:

```
docker exec -it <container or id> /bin/bash <your command>
```

So you are inside your container